# jQuery - show and hide div on hover using closest selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to simply achieve the show/hide feature on hover using the `hover` function of jquery.

However not able to show and hide the particular `div`. When I hover over the current `span` tag I want only the current(closest) `div` to hide and the closest or next possible `div` to be shown.

But currently since the class names are same, it is showing all the `divs`

[FIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/u9xorn8b/3/)

HTML structure:

```
<div class="parentCat">
    <div class="imageContainer">
        <span class="hoverEffect">Some Image</span>
    </div>
    <div class="showContainer">
        <span>New Image</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="parentCat">
    <div class="imageContainer">
        <span class="hoverEffect">Some Image</span>
    </div>
    <div class="showContainer">
        <span>New Image</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can't do that. You are binding the hover event to a child element of div that is being hidden. Once the div hides, you can't possibly maintain the hover of side item because it doesn't show in the window anymore. That is whats causing the crazy flicker effect you are seeing.

Answer (score 3):

If you shift the event to the parent element, everything becomes simpler:

```
$('.ca').hover(function () {
    $('.imageContainer', this).hide();
    $('.showContainer', this).show();

}, function () {
    $('.imageContainer', this).show();
    $('.showContainer', this).hide();
});
```

[Updaated working example](http://jsfiddle.net/qsLg1ry5/).

Comment: my requirement was to get it working as per the question. I can work around by trying to make it work using a `not` selector. http://jsfiddle.net/qsLg1ry5/1/      how can i not hover as in the attached fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

If you want this effect, you need to alter your code. The div which has the hover event can't be one that you are hiding. It is also good practice to nest the related divs INSIDE of a parent div. I believe this is what you are looking for.

HTML

```
  <div class="ca hoverEffect" style="height:40%">
      <div class="imageContainer">
          <span>Some Image</span>
      </div>
      <div class="showContainer">
          <span>New Image</span>
      </div>
  </div>
```

JS

```
$('.hoverEffect').hover(function () {
    $(this).find('.imageContainer').hide();
    $(this).find('.showContainer').show();

}, function () {
    $(this).find('.imageContainer').show();
    $(this).find('.showContainer').hide();
});
```

[Working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u9xorn8b/12/)

Comment: my requirement was to get it working as per the question. I can work around by trying to make it work using a `not` selector. http://jsfiddle.net/qsLg1ry5/1/      how can i not hover as in the attached fiddle.

Comment: You would have to bind the hover event to the parent container, it is the only way.

Comment: i have changed the fiddle a bit. I want one class to not do the hover part. please check the fiddle in above comment.